# Using rxjs to create a 'complex' object using combination operators

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to figure out how to translate a common iterative pattern into reactive rxjs. Let's say I'm trying to build an object called SchoolSchedule composed of single days off and Vacations.

```
class SchoolSchedule {
  schoolName: string;
  districtName: string;
  singleDaysOff: Array<moment.Moment> = new Array<moment.Moment>();
  vacations: Array<Vacation> = new Array<Vacation>();

  constructor(schoolName: string, districtName: string) {
    this.schoolName = schoolName;
    this.districtName = districtName;
  }
}

class Vacation {
  startDate: moment.Moment;
  endDate: moment.Moment;

  constructor(startDate: moment.Moment, endDate: moment.Moment) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
  }
}
```

I create instances of this class from a json file

```
{
  "daysOff": [
    {
      "name": "Your Elementary",
      "district": "Some County",
      "single": ["9/3", "11/12", "1/21"],
      "vacations": ["11/21-11/23", "12/20-1/4", "2/18-2/22"] 
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

In non-reacive logic, I parse each JSON item. First, I create the SchoolSchedule instance. Then I parse the sub-items 'single' and 'vacations' to populate the SchoolSchedule instance. How do I accomplish this with a combination of observables in a reactive way?

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
import { Observable, of, from, zip } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, map } from 'rxjs';
import moment from 'moment';

import DAYS_OFF from 'days_off.json';

const schoolSchedules = new Array<SchoolSchedule>();
const daysOffBySchool = from(DAYS_OFF['daysOff']).pipe(
  switchMap((schoolDayOffsJSON) => zip( 
    new Observable((observer) => {
       const schoolSchedule = new SchoolSchedule(schoolDayOffsJSON.name, schoolDayOffsJSON.district);
       observer.next(schoolSchedule);
       observer.complete();
    }),
    zip(
      from(schoolDayOffsJSON.single).pipe(
        switchMap((dateStr: string) => {
           return new Observable((observer) => {
              observer.next(moment(dateStr + '/2019', 'M/D/YYYY'));
              observer.complete();
           })
        })
      )
    ), 
    zip(
      from(schoolDayOffsJSON.single).pipe(
        map((dateRangeStr: string) => dateRangeStr.split('-')),
        switchMap(dateStr: string) => zip(
          return new Observable((observer) => {
              observer.next(moment(dateStr + '/2019', 'M/D/YYYY'));
              observer.complete();
          }),
          return new Observable((observer) => {
              observer.next(moment(dateStr + '/2019', 'M/D/YYYY'));
              observer.complete();
          })
        )),
        map((dateRanges: Array<moment.Moment>) => return new Vacation(dateRanges(0), dateRanges(1)))
      )
    )
  )),
  map((results) => {
    const schoolSchedule: SchoolSchedule = results[0];
    const singleDaysOff: Array<moment.Moment> = results[1];
    const vacations: Array<Vacation> = results[2];
    schoolSchedule.singleDaysOff = singleDaysOff;
    return schoolSchedule;
  }),
);
daysOffBySchool.subscribe((schoolSchedule: SchoolSchedule) => schoolSchedules.push(schoolSchedule));
```

Needless to say, this doesn't work. This is a tough ask, but what am I doing wrong? What should I be doing? I realize that it would much easier if I didn't break this up into a bunch of observables, but I feel that I wouldn't be able to escape this pattern with more complicated logic later on; so it's best to get it right - right now.

Comment: you can just use normal array operators, coz what you are doing are just some sync operation not async.

Comment: The tool should suite the needs and as much as I enjoy RxJs I would not use it for this use case

Comment: I only chose this example because it's an 'easy' scenario that's trivial to replicate. You'd run into the same logic if you were trying to build the same object using a API structured like my sample JSON file.

Comment: @chaostheory its not clear what API endpoints you have, weather API gives you static one-time values or it keeps emitting values and if schoolSchedules should accumulate those. We could be more helpful, if you'd define API.  _Anyhow, for me it sometimes is easier to write code using Promises and then refactor it to use Streams_

Comment: @Kos I could be wrong but you can extrapolate it from my example. Just substitute an API service for my local datasource. I just disagree with both Fan and Leon about this not being a good use case for rxjs. I'll create a new question to simplify. My main question is how do I chain combination operators with other operators like map? It looks like this was possible with rxjs 5, but due to deprecations I'm not sure how it's possible with rxjs 6.

Comment: @chaostheory, yeah, a simplified example would help! At the moment, its hard to advise something particular. Therefore, another generic advice :) . Understand what you want to get, Object of Observables *or* Observable of Objects -- and ensure you get it. Insert `tap`s and check it. Also give a try to "projection functions" to combine values from streams (see [`zip`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/zip/) example that joins values) and [`of`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/of/) instead of [`constructor`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/constructor/). GL